# Verilog : Using previous generate iteration's wire in current iteration

Tags: verilog

For background, I am trying to implement something like this:

[image]

My idea was to use a couple of nested generate statements to first create each of the 4 stages, then the second to create each mux in that stage. I can create the muxes just fine, but when trying to generate each stage I am running into problems. Specifically when defining the wires between stages.

Is there any way to generate unique wires in each generate iteration and have them be accessed by the next iteration? How would you specify the beginning and endpoints differently?

I imagine trying to make a shift register or adder using a generate statement would have the same problem.

One solution I thought of was to create a multidimensional wire array, but since each index needs to be a different size, is that possible? I could just define them all as the maximum size and only use the bits I need (and let the rest be hopefully optimized away), but this seems inefficient.

Edit: Here is the code as I have it so far, I am actually doing 6 stages (but theres no picture for that one), implementing my inefficient solution above:

```
wire [64:1]data [6:0];

generate
genvar s;
// Creates six mux stages for each input
for(s=6; s>0; s--) begin
  genvar i;
  // Creates muxes to reduce input lines
  for (i=0; i<((2**s)/2); i++) begin
    assign data[s-1][32-i] = inputIn[s] ? data[s][64-((i*2)+1)] : data[s][64-(i*2)];
  end
end
endgenerate

assign outputOut = data[0][64];
```

But I would like to not have to create 7 64 bit wires and actually have the wires sized to their need. This could be done using the genvar to constrain the ranges, but the problem lies in hooking them up in the for loop correctly.

Comment: Is that an assignment while learning features of Verilog? Because in practice you would write selector in one line `assign Y = data[idx];`, without explicitly instantiating modules and wires.

Comment: No, it is not an assignment. I am aware how to create a mux, but in this case you need to connect them with wires.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the intermediate wires between the stages inside the generate loops

```
wire Ain[0:15];
genvar Cv,Bv,Av;

wire Din[0:1];
mux2 Dm( Y,D ,Din[0], Din[1]);
for (Cv=0;Cv<2;Cv=Cv+1) begin : Clevel
   wire Cin[0:1];
   mux2 Cm( Din[Cv], C, Cin[0], Cin[1]);
   for (Bv=0;Bv<2;Bv=Bv+1) begin : Blevel
      wire Bin[0:1];
      mux2 Bm( Cin[Bv], B, Bin[0], Bin[1]);
      for (Av=0;Av<2;Av=Av+1) begin : Alevel
          mux2 Am(Bin[Bv], B, Bin[8*Cv+4*Bv+2*Av], Bin[8*Cv+4*Bv+2*Av+1]);
      end
   end
end
```

This might not be exactly hooked up the way your picture shows, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: That's not exactly what I am trying to do, instead of having separate for loops for C, B, A, you would have a single for loop for the muxes and then an outer for loop for the C, B, A stages.

Comment: I posted my code so far of what I am trying to do to explain better.